# Getting specific rows in a data.table with specific criteria

Tags: r, subset

I would like a subset of specific rows of a dataset that meet certain criteria, and this is the criteria i would like to run

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(DT)-1)){
if(DT$IBTKR2[i]==DT$IBTKR2[i+1]&
 DT$AMASKCD[i]==DT$AMASKCD[i+1]&
 DT$IRECCD[i]!=3&DT$IRECCD[i+1]==3){
 form a subset that includes rows DT[i+1]}}
```

Essentially what it means is that if IBTKR2 for the row and the row below it is equal, the look at AMASKCD, if the row and the row below it is equal3, look at IRECCD, if IRECCD for the row is not equals to 3 and the row below it is equals to 3, I would like to take this row and for a subset.

below is a sample of my dataset

```
   Row IBTKR2  AMASKCD IRECCD ANNDATS
    1   @0CC    71476   1   20000704
    2   @0CC    71476   1   20001204
    3   @0CF    19813   3   20000831
    4   @0CF    47104   3   20000420
    5   @0CF    47340   3   20000418
    6   @0CF    48938   3   20000821
    7   @0CF    56117   2   20000330
    8   @0CF    56117   3   20000413
    9   @0CF    56117   2   20000526
    10  @0CF    56117   3   20000713
    11  @0CF    56117   2   20000801
    12  @0CF    56117   3   20000804
    13  @0CF    58875   3   20000609
    14  @0CF    58875   1   20000822
    15  @0CF    74030   3   20001027
```

and i should get a subset of

```
  Row IBTKR2  AMASKCD IRECCD ANNDATS 
    8   @0CF    56117   3   20000413
    10  @0CF    56117   3   20000713
    12  @0CF    56117   3   20000804
```

Comment: `database` seems like an inappropriate tag for this. The default R data structure is called a `data.frame`. Are you using a `data.frame`? You also use the word `datatable` in your title, which makes it seem like you might be using the popular `data.table` R package, but your syntax isn't consistent with `data.table`. (Well, your syntax isn't really consistent with `data.frame`s either...) Either way, please clear up *what* your data actually is (data.frame in R, data.table in R with the data.table package).

Comment: I don't see a question. This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `shift` to get the next/previous row by using the `type` argument, convert the logical vector to row index (`.I`) and extract the rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT) #in case the dataset is not a `data.table`
DT[DT[, .I[IBTKR2==shift(IBTKR2, type = "lead", fill= IBTKR2[1]) & 
        AMASKCD == shift(AMASKCD, type = "lead", fill = AMASKCD[1]) & 
        (IRECCD !=3) &  shift(IRECCD, type = "lead", fill= IRECCD[1])==3]]+1]
#   Row IBTKR2 AMASKCD IRECCD  ANNDATS
#1:   8   @0CF   56117      3 20000413
#2:  10   @0CF   56117      3 20000713
#3:  12   @0CF   56117      3 20000804
```